# Horizontal scrollbar HTML

Tags: html, css, scroll

I found a family treeview like [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) and the design is devastated if there are many children and won't fit to the screen. How can a horizontal scrollbar be applied to it? Thank you very much. Here is the CSS.

```
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

And this is the HTML used by the site. Mine branches so many times.

```
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"> Hello </a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have this `<div class="tree" style ="overflow-x:scroll">` but scrollbar doesn't work. And whenever I restore the window, the tree is distorted and the scrollbar is fixed and doesn't scroll. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add your HTML part here??

Comment: Hi @SureshPonnukalai I already added it. Thanks.

Comment: you can give a `max-width` to `div.tree` like this `div.tree{ max-width:90%;
  overflow-x:scroll;}` and scrollbar will appear only when the max-width is `90%`.

Comment: Thanks @KheemaPandey but I tried it and the tree is still distorted and the scrollbar is fixed and doesn't scroll. I also tried 100% but the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer..

You need to updated the .tree li class like below.

```
.tree li {
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

I have created the working jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4yQ/

Answer (score 0):

do not quite understand your question, I realized that you need a scroll, mutations both in the resolution of the window or what would it be permanent? and then scroll to your version will always be present, if you still need a scroll when changing screen resolution, then use honey requests like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .tree {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I put this in the CSS but the problem is still there. My problem is that the tree won't extend to the right (scrollbars are fixed and can;t be scrolled) if there are many children. Instead, it goes to the next line which distorts the treeview.

Comment: and the height and width of the parent container must be specified ?

Comment: scrolling works when specified width and height and overflow content appears scroll

Comment: I think that you need to specify the width and height

Comment: Thanks, did it. But only vertical scrollbar works. Horizontal scrollbar is still useless.

Comment: Well, apparently enough width to display content

Comment: But the tree is distorted. I have dual monitor here so when I expand the window the tree displays okay which means there's nothing wrong with the CSS except for the distortion of the tree so the scrollbar is needed.

Comment: eg put the width and height of 100 pixels for example and you will see that there will be a horizontal scroll and

Comment: now honestly do not understand why horizontal scrolling? the fact that the web designing avoid horizontal scrolls is considered bad form, in all screen resolutions gorilontalnoy prokrutnik should not be vertical please as many

Comment: I already did that. Yes the width is now limited to 100px but the tree is more distorted now.

Comment: ask any web developer, and he will tell you that the gorizontal scroll bad idea

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I understand horizontal scroll being a bad idea. But the horizontal scrolling won't last forever. It is just needed when the monitor is square-shaped (like mine) and there's not enough "space" to display the whole tree view.

Comment: That's why I needed the scroll feature. So it won't be distorted.

Comment: Well then we go back to the adaptive design, advise you to read books or use the bootstrap framework is easy to learn, the latest version is already adaptive ie adjust to any screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Make the total `width 100%` put that on the css of the main div of the content

Comment: Thanks but the tree is still distorted. No matter what the width is, the tree is distorted (but the width changes and the distortion is based on the width).

Answer (score 0):

Example: You have the box where the family tree is in named something like: Tree box. Add a maximum width to it like `width: 1200px;` Now you make inside the `div` another `div`like: 
HTML:

```
<div id="treebox">
<div id="treecontent">
[put your html here]
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#treebox{
height:100%;
width:1200px;
}

#treecontent{
width: 100%;
or
width:1600px;
}
```

This should pop up a scrollbar.

You need to lock up the content in a `div` which I named treebox here. And put the content in another `div` which is bigger.

Comment: Thank you but the scrollbar still doesn't work. I did those two `div`s and the `css` but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

got it working for you on here: http://jsfiddle.net/A3yh9/5/ It might look a little screwed up thats because I added alot of children not paying attention to place them nice. This should fix it or else its something on your own side not the code just copy paste the this in your CSS:

```
.tree {  
    height:100%;
    width:960px;
}

.treecontent2{
    width:100%;
}

/*in the .tree put any width u want./
```

and add a `div` right under the `.tree` div you already have and dont forget to close it on the far bottom underneath all your content but above your `</div>` of your `.tree div`

Comment: Actually he don't want to break any content in next line. Your answer giving break when i reduced the browser window.

Answer (score -1):

I never trust CSS in the HTML "style=""" Element. Have you tried to put it in the CSS directly? Please try this:

```
.tree{
   overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's just the same. And whenever I restore the window, the tree is distorted and the scrollbar is fixed and doesn't scroll.